# How to encrypt/decrypt passwords in blueprint.xml?

Tags: java, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I want to set user name & password for RedHat AMQ.
As password could not be plain text, want to specify in encrypted way.

```xml
<bean class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent" id="activemq">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="${activemq.brokerURL}"/>
        <property name="userName" value="${activemq.userName}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${activemq.password}"/>
    </bean>
```

```
activemq.userName=jboss
activemq.password=ENC(kOPUJKK141oluf4XZC91iw==)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding Jasypt dependency in pom.xml file such as-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jasypt</artifactId>
    <version>x.x.x</version> <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
</dependency>
```

It encode the values in property file such as .CFG file and decode the same whenever using inside the project at runtime. The detail of this is available at [link](https://camel.apache.org/jasypt.html).

Comment: Good to know this.

Comment: I will try and get back.

Answer (score 0):

I made it possible by adding property-place holder as below:

ENC(kOPUJKK141oluf4XZC91iw==)

```xml
<enc:property-placeholder>
        <enc:encryptor class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
            <property name="config">
                <bean class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig">
                    <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES"/>
                    <property name="passwordEnvName" value="JASYPT_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </enc:encryptor>
</enc:property-placeholder>
```